# how to add "wildcard-specific wildcard" via snakemake checkpoint

Tags: snakemake

I can't find appropriate words to describe my need, please see the code.
My ideal workflow would do this:
I have known the categories that will be created during the workflow (`cates`)
I don't know how many files and what files would be created in each category (`files`)
For each category, rule `create_file` will be run first.
And then the checkpoint is triggered, I will know what files have been created for each category.
Then, for each file created in the `create_file` rule, a mock rule `append_to_file_name` take the file as input, and do the operation.

Files produced in `create_file` is wildcard specific so I call my need as "wildcard-specific" wildcard

```py
cates=["A", "B"]
# pretend that you don't know about the files about to be created
files={
    "A": ["a.txt", "b.txt"],
    "B": ["c.txt", "d.txt"]
}

def get_append_to_file_output(wildcards):
    files = glob_wildcards(f"{wildcards.cate}/{{file}}.txt").sample
    appened = expand(f"{wildcards.cate}/{{file}}_append.txt", file = files)
    return appened


rule all:
    input:
        get_append_to_file_output,


checkpoint create_file:
    output: ddd=directory("{cate}"),
    run:
        from pathlib import Path
        Path(output.ddd).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
        for file in files[wildcards.cate]:
            Path(file).touch()


rule append_to_file_name:
    input: ddd="{cate}",
    output: "{cate}/{file}_append.txt",
    run:
        from pathlib import Path
        Path(output[0]).touch()
```

Comment: I saw you marked this cross-post on Biostars. ([Biostarts post](https://www.biostars.org/p/9528216/)). It is always best to indicate cross-posts all the locations you post the same question. For example, if someone later updates the Biostars post with a great solution, those finding this thread would potentially miss out without a link back to that post being available here.

Comment: @Wayne Thank you for the advise! I will do this next time.

Answer (score 0):

```py
cates=["A", "B"]
# pretend that you don't know about the files about to be created
files={
    "A": ["a", "b"],
    "B": ["c", "d"]
}

def get_append_to_file_output(wildcards):
    cate_dir = checkpoints.create_file.get(**wildcards).output.ddd
    files = glob_wildcards(f"{cate_dir}/{{file}}.txt").file
    print(files)
    appened = expand(f"results/append_filename/{wildcards.cate}/{{file}}_append.txt", file = files)
    return appened


rule all:
    input:
        expand("results/flags/{cate}_aggregate.flag", cate=cates)


checkpoint create_file:
    output: 
        ddd=directory("results/create_file/{cate}"),
    run:
        from pathlib import Path
        Path(output.ddd).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
        for file in files[wildcards.cate]:
            Path(f"{output.ddd}/{file}.txt").touch()


rule append_to_filename:
    input: 
        ddd=rules.create_file.output.ddd
    output: 
        appended="results/append_filename/{cate}/{file}_append.txt"
    shell:
        "cp {input.ddd}/{wildcards.file}.txt {output.appended}"

rule fake_aggregate:
    input: 
        get_append_to_file_output
    output: 
        touch("results/flags/{cate}_aggregate.flag")
```

I've solved this by adding a fake aggregating rule